# How to find position of point in 3d undergoing coordinate system rotation

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotation

I have solid body at a given point P (a, b, c) in a static coordinate system (xyz) centred at the origin. This solid body however has a certain rotation of its own and I need to figure out the direction to the origin with respect to the coordinate system of the body (XYZ).

For this example say that the x directions are "forward", y is "up", z is "right" of whatever reference point in a given coordinate system.

Say the body is at P (10, 15, -5). The "front" of this body (its own X axis) is facing along the unit vector <0.866, 0, -0.5> and the "top" of this body (its own Y axis) is facing <0.3, 0.8, 0.519>, directions that are defined in the static xyz. I did ensure that these two unit vectors are orthogonal. I need to find the direction towards the origin of xyz in this XYZ.

My strategy was that I would take the static system and rotate it without translation (xyz --> x'y'z') to be parallel with the body's (XYZ). In other words, x' and X would be parallel, as would y' and Y (consequently, z' and Z as well). Then, I'd find the vector from the origin in x'y'z' to P (which does not move) and just flip that around and normalize to get what I need.

Problem is my education only covered how to do this in two dimensions and that was several years ago at this point. I can't seem to get my head around the resources I've found for higher dimensions. I've figured out how to do it if I only had to do one rotation, but to align the systems I need to do two rotations. This is to be put into a python program so I probably won't be able to do any calculus, but matrices are possible. Can someone show me how I would proceed with this using the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to think of this as two rotations, but a single transformation. Luckily, rotations are linear transformations, which makes this an easy matrix problem.

Let $(\hat{e}_X, \hat{e}_Y, \hat{e}_Z)$ be the unit vectors in the $xyz$ coordinate system defined by the body's orientation. Here, $\hat{e}_X=[0.866, 0, -0.5]$, $\hat{e}_Y=[0.3, 0.8, 0.519]$, and $\hat{e}_Z=\hat{e}_X \times \hat{e}_Y$. To start, I'm going to answer a related question: assuming the body is at the static origin, given a vector in $XYZ$-body coordinates, what is the vector in $xyz$-static coordinates. We'll call the matrix that performs this conversion $T$.

Let's say that the $X$-vector of your body happens to point at the origin, which is one unit away. Then,
$$T\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} = \hat{e}_X.$$
The $[1,0,0]$ is the unit vector along the $X$-coordinate in the body coordinate system. This tells us that the first column of $T$ is the column-vector form of $\hat{e}_X$. This works for any matrix: the product of a matrix and a vector which is all $0$s except for a single $1$ at teh $i$th position is the $i$th column of the matrix.

Similarly,
$$T\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \hat{e}_Y.$$
$$T\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} = \hat{e}_Z.$$
So, the transform from the body to the static-coordinate system is given by
$$T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
| & | & | \\
\hat{e}_X & \hat{e}_Y & \hat{e}_X \times \hat{e}_Y \\
| & | & |
\end{bmatrix}$$
where the vertical bars indicate column vectors.

But, this isn't quite what we want. We want the static coordinate in the body coordinate system. So, we need the inverse of $T$:
$$\vec{v}_{static} = T\vec{v}_{body}$$
$$\implies$$
$$\vec{v}_{body} = T^{-1}\vec{v}_{static}$$
Luckily, $T$ is an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), which we know because its column vectors are an orthonormal set, and which means its inverse is just the transpose.
$$T^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
- & \hat{e}_X & - \\
- & \hat{e}_Y & - \\
- & \hat{e}_X \times \hat{e}_Y & -
\end{bmatrix}$$
where the horizontal lines indicate row vectors. So, using your body coordinates,
$$T^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.866 & 0 & -0.5 \\
0.3 & 0.8 & 0.519 \\
0.4 & -0.599 & 0.693
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, you want the static origin in the body coordinate system. From the body's point of view, the origin is at [-10, -15, 5], the reverse of the body's position. So, the body coordinate is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0.866 & 0 & -0.5 \\
0.3 & 0.8 & 0.519 \\
0.4 & -0.599 & 0.693
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-10\\
-15\\
5\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-11.16\\
-12.405\\
8.45
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If you want any other coordinate, you need to start by subtracting the position of the body so you get the position relative to the body ($\vec{v}_{static} = \vec{P} + \vec{v}_{body} \implies \vec{v}_{body} = \vec{v}_{static} - \vec{P}$. So, the total transform is
$$\vec{v}_{body} = T^{-1}\left(\vec{v}_{static} - \vec{P}\right).$$
In the example above with the origin, $\vec{v}_{static} = \vec{0}$.

Comment: Thanks so much for that write up. Makes perfect sense. I'm just about to go to bed now, but I'll try it in the morning.

Comment: @Graham Did it work?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, forgot to reply. Yes it works like a charm. I verified the results with a cad program. Thanks a bunch.